# PHP Still Loads Old Version of cURL after upgrade

Tags: curl, php-curl

Debian 14.04, FPM, PHP 5.5.x. Had to upgrade cURL from 7.35 to 7.47.1. After upgrade version shows correct 7.47.1; however, info.php shows 7.35. My educated guess is the curl.so extension is still 7.35 that the php.ini is pointing to; however, how do I update this php extension to use the new 7.47.1 libraries of cURL? [Another post; 18295360] was not clearly answered.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to recompile PHP pointing it to the new cURL headers and libraries in order to get the new version.  When built, it was linked to the older version of cURL and will need to be recompiled to use the new version.

Comment: Thanks Drew! Appears compile php cURL can be found here 4976971, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Followup: Ok, so php now sees the updated curl module, what I did on Ubuntu: apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev; apt-get install checkinstall then apt-get remove php5-curl; service apache2 restart; apt-get install php5-curl, service apache2 restart; service php5-fpm restart; check info.php - Bingo! whew.